# Is there a concept or implementation similar to java RMI in dot net (C#)?

Tags: c#, java, .net, rmi

Is there a concept or implementation of RMI like concept in .net?
Can we program network programming in C#/VB just like RMI in java?
Such as stub,skeleton,registry like concepts.

Answer (score 7):

The closest analogy to RMI in Java is .Net Remoting.  Here are a couple of links comparing the techonologies

- [Java RMI vs .Net Remoting](https://web.archive.org/web/20060721210444/http://students.cs.tamu.edu/jchen/cpsc689-608/comparison/l0c0607-framework_comp_lichen.pdf)
- [Migrating Java RMI to .Net Remoting](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pk_khuman/RMIto.NETRemoting01162006052210AM/RMIto.NETRemoting.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link, although the first is dead I'm afraid!

Comment: @obfuscation: I fixed the link